# locked or unlocked the conditional formatting cells xlsxwriter

Tags: python, locking, xlsxwriter, unlock

I have protected the complete sheet, then I am unlocking the conditional formatting cell, but its not working for me.

Please help any one.

```
format1 = wb.add_format({'bg_color':#87c2ff ,'locked': False})

ws.conditional_format(colrang, {'type':     'cell',
                                    'criteria': 'not equal to',
                                     'value':   rowIndx,
                                    'format':   format1,
                                    })
```

But the cell is not unlocked.

Comment: Please show a minimal working example with an traceback errors, if any.

Answer (score 1):

> I have protected the complete sheet, then I am unlocking the conditional formatting cell, but its not working for me.

This isn't supported in conditional formats in Excel. From the XlsxWriter [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html#the-conditional-format-method):

> **Note**
>
> In Excel, a conditional format is superimposed over the existing cell format and not all cell format properties can be modified. Properties that **cannot** be modified in a conditional format are font name, font size, superscript and subscript, diagonal borders, all alignment properties and all protection properties.